# While binding the gridview throwing an error in a process?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am copying the selcted data from on grid to another on the click of a button. I am using postgre SQl for my apllication. Here is the link for the [HTML](http://shrib.com/kOon1F0d). I am binding the data in as

```
 NpgsqlDataAdapter adp;
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projop"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindPrimaryGrid();
            BindSecondaryGrid();
        }
    }

     private void BindSecondaryGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
        gvSelected.DataSource = dt;
        gvSelected.DataBind();
    }
    private void BindPrimaryGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select user_id, username,screen_name from users", conn);
        dt = new DataTable("users");
        adp.Fill(dt);
        gvAll.DataSource = dt;
        gvAll.DataBind();
```

After the selection of the data & button click as

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
        SetData();
        BindSecondaryGrid();
    }
private void GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
        else
            dt = CreateDataTable();
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gvAll.HeaderRow
                            .Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");
        for (int i = 0; i < gvAll.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chkAll.Checked)
            {
                dt = AddRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);
            }
            else
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvAll.Rows[i]
                                .Cells[0].FindControl("chk");
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    dt = AddRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt = RemoveRow(gvAll.Rows[i], dt);
                }
            }
        }
        ViewState["SelectedRecords"] = dt;
    }

    private void SetData()
    {
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gvAll.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");
        chkAll.Checked = true;
        if (ViewState["SelectedRecords"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords"];
            for (int i = 0; i < gvAll.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk");
                if (chk != null)
                {
                    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("CustomerID = '" + gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "'");
                    chk.Checked = dr.Length > 0;
                    if (!chk.Checked)
                    {
                        chkAll.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here while binding the data in function `btnSubmit_Click` via `BindSecondaryGrid()` showing an error on `gvSelected.DataBind();` in function `BindSecondaryGrid()`.

Error: `DataBinding: 'HttpException - System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'user_id'.`

Edit: Add & Remove Codes

```
  private DataTable AddRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
    {
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("CustomerID = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
        if (dr.Length <= 0)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["CustomerID"] = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ContactName"] = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Complete Name"] = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        return dt;
    }

    private DataTable RemoveRow(GridViewRow gvRow, DataTable dt)
    {
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("CustomerID = '" + gvRow.Cells[1].Text + "'");
        if (dr.Length > 0)
        {
            dt.Rows.Remove(dr[0]);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your AddRow or RemoveRow function codes. Thanks

Comment: @Hatjhie I had added the Add/Remove codes. Please check out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your DataField specified in your GridView is incorrect. Let's try this.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField = "CustomerID" HeaderText = "Customer ID" 
 HtmlEncode = "false" />
<asp:BoundField DataField = "ContactName" HeaderText = "Contact Name" 
HtmlEncode = "false" />
<asp:BoundField DataField = "CompleteName" HeaderText = "Complete Name" 
HtmlEncode = "false" />
```

Please note that the DataField specified must match with the DataRow's name.

I am assuming your Datatable has column as highlighted with **:

> ```
> dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["**CustomerID**"] = gvRow.Cells[1].Text;
> dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["**ContactName**"] = gvRow.Cells[2].Text;
> dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["**CompleteName**"] = gvRow.Cells[3].Text;
> ```

Let me know if this fixed this issue. Thanks